# Interpret terminal escape codes in generic process output

Tags: ansi-term, subprocess

I'm running a `(start-process)` which spits out terminal escape codes into a buffer and it looks ugly. Is there a mode that will interpret these codes into colors? Something similar to whatever `ansi-term` does?

Comment: You do need to set up the plumbing with `ansi-color` but I don't know how that works when you aren't in Comint mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "process sentinel" mentioned in @steve-lorimer's answer if it is OK for you to get color AFTER the process is finished, otherwise you should use "process filter" instead.

Take command `echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"` as an example, you can simply use `comint-output-filter` (I learnt this by reading `shell-command`'s source code)

```el
(let ((process
       (start-process "echo" "*echo*"
                      "echo" "-e" "\e[31mHello World\e[0m")))
  (with-current-buffer (process-buffer process)
    (display-buffer (current-buffer))
    (require 'shell)
    (shell-mode)
    (set-process-filter process 'comint-output-filter)))
```

besides colors, `comint-output-filter` can also handle progress bar (used by commands like `wget`) correctly.

Or you can also make your own filter:

```el
(let ((process
       (start-process "echo" "*echo*"
                      "echo" "-e" "\e[31mHello World\e[0m")))
  (with-current-buffer (process-buffer process)
    (display-buffer (current-buffer))
    (font-lock-mode)
    (set-process-filter
     process
     #'echo-output-filter)))

;; Base on `ordinary-insertion-filter' from (info "(elisp) Filter Functions")
(defun echo-output-filter (proc string)
  (when (buffer-live-p (process-buffer proc))
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
      (let ((moving (= (point) (process-mark proc))))
        (save-excursion
          ;; Insert the text, advancing the process marker.
          (goto-char (process-mark proc))
          (insert (ansi-color-apply string))
          (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point)))
        (if moving (goto-char (process-mark proc)))))))
```

Both of them work from here.

Answer (score 0):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348780/955273) makes reference to `ansi-color-apply-on-region`.

The idea is you use `set-process-sentinel` to get notified when your process exits, and then use `ansi-color-apply-on-region` on the buffer

```
(set-process-sentinel
 (start-process "foo" "*Foo*" foo-command foo-args)
 (lambda (p _m)
   (when (eq 0 (process-exit-status p))
     (with-current-buffer (process-buffer p)
       (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))))
```